# Save Outlook attachment from a specific date using Python

Tags: python, date, email, outlook, email-attachments

I would like to know how I could add the date to this code to save the attachment files n emails from Outlook: for example, I would like to save the files found between 20/04/2020 and 01/01/2020. Do you have any idea, please?

```
outputDir = r"C:\Users\CMhalla\Desktop\attachment"
i=0
for m in messages:
    if m.SenderEmailAddress == 'info@outlook.com':
       body_content=m.Body
       for attachment in m.Attachments:
           i=i+1
           attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(outputDir,attachment.FileName + str(i)+'.xlsx'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line

```
for m in messages:
```

to (off the top of my head):

```
for m in messages.Restrict("([ReceivedTime] <= '04/20/2020') AND ([ReceivedTime] >= '01/01/2020') AND (SenderEmailAddress = 'info@outlook.com')"):
```

Comment: Thank you so muuuch!!

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) and [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the `Items` class to get items that correspond to your conditions.

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

You may also find the [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/) article helpful where a similar search criteria is used.

Comment: I think that this is not really the case since I am looking for extracting emails from a specific date :(

Comment: That's exactly what you need! You just get email for the specified time frame.